# Why I'm not getting banner and background mode push notiifications while receiving message on console ios10.2

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

These are my settings:

[image: project settings]

and

[image: Project settings2]

This is my appDelegate

```
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
#endif
//#import "FIRMessaging.h"
//#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GRATERTHAN_OR_EQUALTO(v)  ([[[UIDevice       currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] !=   NSOrderedAscending)
@import UIKit;
@import Firebase;
@import FirebaseMessaging;
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >=   __IPHONE_10_0
#endif
@interface AppDelegate ()
{
NSTimer *timer1;
}
@end
// Copied from Apple's header in case it is missing in some cases (e.g.     pre-Xcode 8 builds).
#ifndef NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max
#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max 1299 
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate 
NSString *const kGCMMessageIDKey = @"gcm.message_id";

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <=   NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
      // iOS 7.1 or earlier. Disable the deprecation warnings.
 #pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
    UIRemoteNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
    (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
    [application  registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:allNotificationTypes];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
   } else {
     // iOS 8 or later
     // [START register_for_notifications]
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    } else {
        // iOS 10 or later
 #if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
        UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
        UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
        | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
        | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        }];

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        [FIRMessaging messaging].remoteMessageDelegate = self;
 #endif
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    // [END register_for_notifications]
}

  [FIRApp configure];
 ..../
```

plus all these app delegate call backs

```
     - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application      didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
// If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
// this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
// TODO: Handle data of notification

// Print message ID.
  // if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
 //      NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
//}

 // Print full message.
  NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
 }
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application     didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
  // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
  // TODO: Handle data of notification

// Print message ID.
if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
}

// Print full message.
NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
 }
// [END receive_message]

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >=  __IPHONE_10_0
// Handle incoming notification messages while app is in the  foreground.
 - (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
   willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
     withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
// Print message ID.
NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
}

// Print full message.
NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

// Change this to your preferred presentation option
completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone);
}

  // Handle notification messages after display notification is tapped by the user.
   - (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
      withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
 NSDictionary *userInfo =    response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
  if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {
    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
  }

  // Print full message.
  NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);

  completionHandler();
  }
  #endif
  // [END ios_10_message_handling]

  // [START ios_10_data_message_handling]
  #if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >=   __IPHONE_10_0
  // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
   - (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage   *)remoteMessage {
  // Print full message
  NSLog(@"%@", remoteMessage.appData);
  }
  #endif
// [END ios_10_data_message_handling]

 // [START refresh_token]
 - (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
// Note that this callback will be fired everytime a new token is   generated, including the first
// time. So if you need to retrieve the token as soon as it is available this is where that
// should be done.
NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
NSLog(@"InstanceID token: %@", refreshedToken);

// Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted  before having a token.
[self connectToFcm];

// TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
}
// [END refresh_token]

// [START connect_to_fcm]
- (void)connectToFcm {
// Won't connect since there is no token
if (![[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]) {
    return;
}

// Disconnect previous FCM connection if it exists.
[[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];

[[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");
    }
}];
}
 // [END connect_to_fcm]

  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application  didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"Unable to register for remote notifications: %@", error);
}

  // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
  // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
 // the InstanceID token.
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application  didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
   NSLog(@"APNs token retrieved: %@", deviceToken);

  // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
 [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] setAPNSToken:deviceToken     type:FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox];
 }

 // [START connect_on_active]
 - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
[self connectToFcm];
  }
  // [END connect_on_active]

  // [START disconnect_from_fcm]
  - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
  [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];
  NSLog(@"Disconnected from FCM");
  }
  // [END disconnect_from_fcm]
```

I'm unable to get banners and notifications in background although I get the message in the console e.g.(`- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage   *)remoteMessage` is triggered).

No sounds either and all the provisioning profiles are done, just in case.

Comment: No one has an answer on this...Im dead end lost, i 've searched all the relevant topics , did all the tricks but still in ios10.2 I'm not getting notification when app in background or closed, nor a banner when app on foreground...all I can do is show an alert box when message is reveved in console....anyone has any idea on this..please help

Comment: Did you check, Success response from `applicationDidBecomeActive` `connectToFcm`?

Comment: Yes user3585096, I m getting connected to FCM, and Im getting a token...

Comment: It seems that the internal notification mechanism is not working at all...

Comment: Im having this same issue right now, if I figure it ill let you know and visa versa please and thank you. I thought it wasnt working at all but then noticed the console was printing it :(

Comment: @JosephMckenzie nothing my side yet, I'm like this over a month....im downloading Xcode update 8.2.1, maybe this will have some fix.....ill get back to you.

Comment: no nothing changed with Xcode update!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved it . You need to set an app ID in apple developer site , and enable push notifications on both development and distribution( don't forge t the bundle id must match the bundle id on Xcode).After that you need to create a provisioning profile for that app ID and install it in your mac.Last but not least you need to put in the Firebase console the p12 file generated from the keychain access . In the firebase console you have a grey gear button next to overview. You select that and then cloud messaging tab and you upload the p12 certificate file generated in the keychain access when you expand the push notification certification and export the p12 file.You need to enter a password and upload it to firebase.

Comment: Funny enough after fixing the problem, in development mode, when i released an update of the app the notifications stopped working there....Another nightmare is on!

Comment: Posted a follow up question three weeks ago, as push notifications now work only in development mode and not in production.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43306068/im-not-getting-push-notifications-in-production-in-ios-10

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [FIRApp configure] before the if statement!

Comment: Im afraid its not that i just moved the [FIRApp configure] at the beginning of the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, but still the same...

Comment: actually just tested on my iPhone 5,2 the firebase messaging example and it does the same thing there too...receiving on console no banner no background notification.