# Im not getting push notifications in production in iOS 10

Tags: firebase, push-notification, ios10, firebase-cloud-messaging, production

Im using Firebase messaging and I was able to get notifications in development mode, but as soon as I archived my bundle and upload it to App Store I'm not getting notifications in test flight. Because I have a previous version of the app with iOS 7, i can see the notifications are arriving to that device,(so I suppose my profiles and certificates are ok) but not on thee  device using iOS 10, and the test flight built.

Comment: IS it something I'm doing wrong and nobody cares to answer my questions?

Comment: No one yet has encountered this problem? Heeeeeeeelp